# requests не импортируется

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

requents инсталлировал, написал так:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=languege:python&sort=stars'
r = requests.get(url)

print('status code:', r.status_code)
```

все равно ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: а что скажет комманда pip install requests?

Comment: @Manul74 все нормально вроде

Comment: У вас несколько версий Python установлено?

Comment: @Александр нет, одна, 3.7.7

Comment: У вас операционная система Windows?

Comment: @Александр да, 10ый

Comment: Откройте cmd введите py и покажите вывод

Comment: @Александр Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108754/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: давайте. Я уже там.

Comment: Вы используете VS Code?

Comment: @Viewed нет вроде